# How do I specify the return value in a custom YUI cell editor?

Tags: javascript, yui, yui-datatable, yui-editor

I created a custom cell editor that extends BaseCellEditor but how do I specify the value of the cell that will be saved/returned?

Setting the this.value = "new value" doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out you have to overwrite getInputValue() the same way you have to overwrite renderForm()

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/CellEditor.js.html

Ctrl-f to find the getInputValue() YUI automatically formats the data using the formatter you specified.